# Unable to Update Image in realtime database using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am trying to update the image using the react native realtime database and instead of updating new image is being inserted which i don't want. Please help and thanks in advance. here is
my code

My database:

[image]

```
launchImageLibrary(options,(response) => {
   ImgToBase64.getBase64String(response.assets[0].uri)
   .then(async (base64String) => {
    var userUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let source = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+base64String;
    await UpdateImage(source,userUID).
    then(() => {
      setImgObj(response.assets[0].uri);
    }) 
    .catch(err => console.log("error ======> ",err));
   })
 })
};

const UpdateImage = async (image,uid) => {
  try {
      return await Firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid)
  .update ({
       image:image,

      }).then((data)=>{
      console.log('Updated  imge is =====>  ' , data)
  }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log('error ' , error)
  })
  } catch (error) {
      console
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid)
  .update ({
    image:image,
  })
```

This write a value to the `image` property of the user overwriting any existing value of that property, so if you run this multiple times you end up with just the last value.

If you want to keep a list of URLs, do:

```
Firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/images')
  .push()
  .set(image)
```

Calling `push()` here adds an item to a list, as explained in the documentation on [appending to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Comment: i try this but not working i want selected image will update only instead all images are updates, how to fix it ?

Comment: "not working" is incredibly hard to help with. Does it make sense from reading my answer why you are only getting one file with your code? If so, does it also make sense why calling `push` will generate a list of files? If so, when you made the code change and stepped through the code, what did see change in the database structure? If nothing changed, was there an error? If not, double check if you made the change correct, and step through the updated code line by line in a debugger - checking the value of each variable on each line to see if it matches what you expect.